# Can a Pokemon learn a move that I previously denied?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

I accidentally stopped Incineroar from learning *Darkest Lariat*, Is there any other way to get it to learn this move? I know it's his signature move but the new setup is crazy weird and I accidentally pressed "do not learn" by accident.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the [Move Reminder](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/movetutors.shtml) will teach you any moves that your Pokémon either knew previously or *had the opportunity to learn previously*.

From [this page on where to find the Move Reminder](https://www.vg247.com/2016/11/21/pokemon-sun-moon-guide-where-to-find-the-move-reminder-and-move-deleter-tutors/):

> The move reminder is the more useful of their pair of NPCs since she lets you re-learn any move that your Pokemon either learned at an earlier level **or had the opportunity to learn at an earlier level.** This includes moves that have been inherited by eggs which is especially handy given that Pokemon can learn additional moves they can’t anywhere else via careful egg breeding.

As to where to *find* her, from the above page:

> The move reminder NPC is found fairly late on in the game for such a crucial area – she’s on Ula'ula Island’s Mount Lanakila. This is a place you’ll only visit once you’ve completed all the various parts of your island trial. She’s next to the shop inside the mountain’s resident Pokemon Center.

Comment: Are you sure she's on ***Poni*** island? I encountered her just yesterday on my way to the League, which I believe should be on Ula'ula island. The serebii link also confirms that she's on Ula'ula.

Comment: Mount Lanakila is on Ula'ula, but you can go to the pokemon center only after completing every Island trials

Comment: @Nolonar thanks for the catch. I would've edited myself but I was asleep :)

Comment: Also she charges you a heart scale per move.